# How do I list all pods that were not created by a controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I need to get a list of all pods that were not created by a controller so I can decide how to handle them before doing a drain on a node.

Otherwise I get the message:

```
error: cannot delete Pods not managed by ReplicationController, ReplicaSet, Job, DaemonSet or StatefulSet (use --force to override) while running the drain.
```

I can find the information by running `kubectl describe <pod>` and looking to see if the Controlled By: is missing but I want to programmatically search all pods on the node and since `kubectl describe` is not designed for that. I need to find an alternative method.

Comment: You might be able to get via json path where the controlled by is null / undefined / missing.

Kubectl json path docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/ (see the bottom for how to query via json path.

Additional helper of kubectl jsonpath: https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/jsonpath/

To pull it all together, I think you can output in json with `-o=json` on a `kubectl get` and see if the data you need is there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can relly on the `ownerReferences` API object to find this:

> $ kubectl explain pod.metadata.ownerReferences
>
> KIND:     Pod
>
> VERSION: v1
>
> RESOURCE: ownerReferences <[]Object>
>
> DESCRIPTION:
>        List of objects depended by this object. If ALL objects in the list have
>        been deleted, this object will be garbage collected. If this object is
>        managed by a controller, then an entry in this list will point to this
>        controller, with the controller field set to true. There cannot be more
>        than one managing controller.

Bare pods (i.e., pods without controllers/owners) will not contain the `ownerReferences` field, so you can use the `--custom-columns` to find out which pods are controlled or not:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,CONTROLLER:.metadata.ownerReferences[].kind,NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace
NAME                               CONTROLLER   NAMESPACE
nginx-85ff79dd56-tvpts             ReplicaSet   default
static-pod1                        <none>       default
static-pod2                        <none>       default
coredns-5644d7b6d9-6hg82           ReplicaSet   kube-system
coredns-5644d7b6d9-wtph7           ReplicaSet   kube-system
etcd-minikube                      <none>       kube-system
kube-addon-manager-minikube        <none>       kube-system
kube-apiserver-minikube            <none>       kube-system
kube-controller-manager-minikube   <none>       kube-system
kube-proxy-fff5c                   DaemonSet    kube-system
kube-scheduler-minikube            <none>       kube-system
storage-provisioner                <none>       kube-system
tiller-deploy-55c9c4b4df-hgzwm     ReplicaSet   kube-system
```

---

If you want only the pod names that are not owned by a controller manager, you can process the output of `kubectl get -o json` with [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) (very useful for post script processing):

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o json | jq -r '.items | map(select(.metadata.ownerReferences == null ) | .metadata.name) | .[]'
static-pod1
static-pod1
etcd-minikube
kube-addon-manager-minikube
kube-apiserver-minikube
kube-controller-manager-minikube
kube-scheduler-minikube
storage-provisioner
```

Comment: Worked great - Thanks